# C programming - array of chars vs array of strings addressing disambiguation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, c-strings

```
char contents[8][2]={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
char* contentsx[8]={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

printf("Contents: %s\n", contents[1]);
printf("Contents: %s\n", &contents[1]);
printf("Contentsx: %s\n", contentsx[1]);
printf("Contentsx: %s\n", &contentsx[1]);
```

prints  :

```
Contents: 2
Contents: 2 
Contentsx:2 
Contentsx: //prints nothing or some garbage character
```

The question is, why **contents[1]** which is the value of element 1,
prints the same result with **&contents[1]**, which is the address of element 1
and by that context why the value  of **contentsx[1]** is different from
**&contentsx[1]** (which has some undefined behaviour)

Comment: m not sure but try with `printf("Contents: %u\n", &contents[1]);` to print address.

Comment: Why should `contentsx[1]` and `&contentsx[1]` be equal? Do you think the `&` means nothing? What if I write `&&&contentsx[1]`, should that be equal to `contentsx[1]`, too?

Comment: I said "by that context" meaning that if  contents[1] has the same value as  &contents[1], that might well be the case with  contentsx[1] and  &contentsx[1]

Comment: Just check the warnings your code generates, they are quite explicit: http://ideone.com/QJ9jbV

Comment: I'm using gcc with -Werror flag on but I don't get any warnings/errors! What do I do wrong?

Comment: -Werror means treat warnings as error. Did you compile with -Wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `contents` is an array of arrays.

`contents[1]` represents the second array in this array of arrays. As such, its name decays into a pointer to its first element, which has size 1. `&contents[1]`, however, points to the whole array, having size 2.

`xcontents[1]` is a `char *` pointing to the exact location of the string given. `&xcontents[1]` is a `char **` pointing to the entry, which is in this case a `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

The `contents` array is an 8x2 array of `char`. Its elements are `char[2]` - arrays of 2 `char`s. Therefore, `contents[1]` is an array of `char[2]` located at index `1`. When you take the address of that array, it is the same as the location of the initial element of that array, i.e. `&contents[1][0]`, which is the same as the location of the initial element of string `"2"`.

Although an address of `char[2]` is *not* what `printf`' expects for its `%s` format specifier, it happens to work in this case, because the address happens to match; however, this is considered undefined behavior.

When you try the same thing on an array of pointers `contentsx`, the result is different: now you are passing an address of the pointer at index `1`, which no longer coincides with the location of the string, causing undefined behavior again. This time, though, the undefined behavior manifests itself in printing nothing, or printing random characters.